# What's the translation of 'dates' as a fruit?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, comida

When referring to the fruit! (no 'fechas' nor 'meeting')
For those Argentinians out there: are there dates in Argentina?

It looks like some sort of 'higo' but that is 'fig', I even thought it is something like a 'pasa' but I still have no clue, but the taste is so familiar!

[image]

Comment: They are harvest in Colombia, in a city called Cali, where Turkish, Jews and the Arabs have migrated for many years.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the Spanish word for the fruit of the date palm is *dátil*.  The [RAE definition](http://www.rae.es/d%C3%A1til) defines it as:

> **1. m.** Fruto de la palmera, de forma elipsoidal prolongada, de unos cuatro centímetros de largo por dos de grueso, cubierto con una película amarilla, carne blanquecina comestible y hueso casi cilíndrico, muy duro y con un surco a lo largo.

According to the Spanish Wikipedia articles on [*Phoenix dactylifera*](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_dactylifera) and [*Dátil*](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A1til), they come from the *palmera datilera* tree and are probably native to Southeast Asia. I'm not from Argentina, but found [another page](http://www.sabelotodo.org/agricultura/palmas/datil.html) that mentions it's been introduced in northeast Argentina:

> La palma datilera se ha introducido en Australia, y en el noreste de Argentina y Brasil, donde puede prosperar en las zonas secas. Dátiles propagados de semillas aparecen en muchas regiones tropicales y sub-tropicales donde son valorados como plantas ornamentales, pero donde el clima no es apto para la producción de fruta.

Comment: Interesting! Datiles... me voy a comer algunos! Gracias!!!